# Sublime Text build and run

Tags: build, sublimetext2

Notepad++ has a "Run" feature where you can simply run "$(full_current_path)" and it will run the file you're working on with its default program.

Is there any way Sublime Text can do this as well?

Answer (score 2):

In ST2, you can set its build system in: Tools > Build System > New Build System

And here you can find the manual https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html